# Webpack won't load relative images from node module css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, npm, webpack

I'm trying to import css (and through that, a relative image path) from a node module.

Adding the npm package works fine,

```
yarn add @claviska/jquery-minicolors
```

Importing the css works fine,

```
@import '~@claviska/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors';
```

But then when I view my site, I get the following webpack error,

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './jquery.minicolors.png'
```

This is the offending image path from the css:

```
.minicolors-sprite {
  background-image: url(jquery.minicolors.png);
}
```

The css, image, and js files are all in the same npm folder:

`node_modules/@claviska/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css`
`node_modules/@claviska/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.png`
`node_modules/@claviska/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.js`

If I copy that image from `/node_modules` and paste it into my webpack `/css` folder then everything works!

**How can I teach webpack to load relative image paths from css included in my node_module packages?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a reasonable solution to this though there are probably better ones.

Moved my css import from my main scss file `src/application.scss`

```
@import '~@claviska/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors';
```

to my main js file `packs/application.js`

```
// Import js
import '@claviska/jquery-minicolors';
// Import css
import '@claviska/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css';
```

It's possible that the `js` and `css` imports need to be in the same document in order for webpack to discover the problematic relative image path `url(jquery.minicolors.png)`.

Would love to hear other suggestions.